# how to calculate distance with mulitiple coordinates using mapdist ? and read Chinese

Tags: r

I am trying to use mapdist function in ggmap package to calculate distance and walking ,driving speed between many places. I have checked the help file , it appears
 that coordinate can be accepted by mapdist ,but can't find out how to input multiple coordinates  ? the following code works,but how to put another coordinate into "g"?or how to put many coordinate in a dataframe, and mapdist can read them ? 
and, can mapdist read in Chinese locations?
Thanks for your reply!

```
g=c(121.754252477584,24.7528993303431)
c=c(121.752751736839,24.7554214120371)
mapdist(g,c,mode=c("driving","walking","bicycling"),output=c("simple"))
```

Comment: Probably better to post this to `http://gis.stackexchange.com/`

Answer (score 7):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I thought I would add this for the help of future folks.

This command I learned from a script on [Github](https://github.com/osPlanning/RGTravelTime/blob/master/GoogleTrTime.R) – initially committed by Peter Schmiedeskamp – which alerted me to the fact that R was capable of grabbing drive-times from the Google Maps API. I used in an [example on my blog](https://github.com/osPlanning/RGTravelTime/blob/master/GoogleTrTime.R) to calculate drive times from various house sales to a city-center location.

`location` is the column containing each observation's long/lat coordinates, in the following format `(-76.218922,36.841287)`. `locMall` is a column in my data set with the long/lat coords of the mall in each row. Just to clarify: each cell in this column had the exact same value, while each cell of `location` was different.  Also something useful: mode can either be `driving`, `walking`, or `bicycling`.

`library(ggmap)`

`library(plyr)`

```
google_results <- rbind.fill(apply(subset(sample, select=c("location", "locMall")), 1, function(x) mapdist(x[1], x[2], mode="driving")))
```

Now let’s look at the results:

```
head(google_results,4)

          from                      to             m    km      miles   sec. minutes
1 (-76.219024, 36.901373) (-76.288018, 36.848950) 10954 10.954  6.806816 986 16.433333
2 (-76.243859, 36.868871) (-76.288018, 36.848950)  7279  7.279  4.523171 662 11.033333
3 (-76.296122, 36.859805) (-76.288018, 36.848950)  2101  2.101  1.305561 301  5.016667
4 (-76.264474, 36.938692) (-76.288018, 36.848950) 12844 12.844  7.981262 934 15.566667
    hours
1 0.27388889
2 0.18388889
3 0.08361111
4 0.25944444
```

*Edit: update. code now requires long, lat.

Comment: This worked great thank you. Out of interest, what purpose does the 1 serve in this section: apply(subset(sample, select=c("location", "locMall")), 1, function(x) mapdist(x[1], x[2], mode="driving"))

Comment: @George - look at `?apply` - the 1 is the `MARGIN` argument which says to apply the function over each row. The other option is 2, which means to apply the function over each column